# running scikit-learn on Sypder with Python 3.5

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to print a accuracy score and get this message:

`<function accuracy_score at 0x0000018A76046840>`

So I am wondering if I am missing a package or is something installed incorrect?

Code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import svm
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y= iris.target
#print (iris.keys)
print('**********')
#print (iris['feature names'])
print('**********')
#print (iris)
#print (iris['data'].shape,'legth: ',len(iris['target']))
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)
clf.fit(X,y)
y_hat=clf.predict(X)
accuracy_score(y, y_hat)
score = accuracy_score
print (score)
```

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Not, here, in the question itself. Edit the question and add the code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are printing the object of function. Instead call the function. Suppose the name of your function is `func`. You are doing something like

```
print(func)
```

instead try to call it by adding parenthesis.

```
print(func())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it must be:

```
score = accuracy_score(y, y_hat)
print (score)
```

You assigned empty function to score.

Your entire code should now be:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import svm
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y= iris.target
#print (iris.keys)
print('**********')
#print (iris['feature names'])
print('**********')
#print (iris)
#print (iris['data'].shape,'legth: ',len(iris['target']))
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)
clf.fit(X,y)
y_hat=clf.predict(X)

score = accuracy_score(y, y_hat)
print (score)
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you very much, sorry first question and should have read how to post code first!

Comment: Don't forget mark question answered (tick on best answer).